# Is there any way to eject cash drawer without paper feed?

Tags: point-of-sale, receipt

We're using a Bixolon SRP-350 receipt printer with a Windows 7 Point of Sale system.  The printer is connected via USB to the PC; the cash drawer is connected to the printer with a special cable.  To open the cash drawer, we issue a printer command.

PROBLEM:
Kicking the cash drawer open always causes the receipt printer to eject some paper.

Any suggestions how to avoid this?

Any suggestions in any language would be helpful; we happen to be using Delphi:

```
  MyPrinter.BeginDoc;
  MyPrinter.Canvas.Font.Name := 'FONTCONTROL';
  MyPrinter.Canvas.Font.Size := 0;
  MyPrinter.Canvas.TextOut (0,0,'A');
  MyPrinter.EndDoc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the Windows Printer configuration for the printer:

```
[Control Panel], 
  Printers, 
    Bixolon SRP-350, [Properties...],
      [Printing Preferences], 
        [Paper Quality], 
          [Paper Source]
          <= Changed from "Automatically Select" to
             "Receipt[Partial cut without paper feeding]"
```